# What are some examples of isotrophic sets?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis, uniform-distribution

What are some examples of isotrophic sets? and is there a "good" way to describe them?

Isotrophic meaning that a random vector X uniformly distributed in the set has the isotrophic property  for all $x \in  R^n $  expected value $ E(\langle x,X\rangle^2 )= ||x||_2 ^2$

Comment: Not sure if this helps but check outhttp://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC28317/

Comment: isotrophic or isotropic?

Comment: @LearningMath I was asking for just some simple examples I mean of course the sphere is one but I'd like to know a little bit more.

Comment: @Henry see changes with the definition of isotrophic I mean

Comment: Cross-posted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/191755, where there is already a proof that no such set exists. Probably the definition given is wrong. Maybe it should be $\mathbb E(\langle x,X\rangle^2)=\|x\|^2$.

Comment: Taking $x$ and $X$ to be column vectors, $\mathbb E\big(\langle x,X\rangle^2\big)=\mathbb E(x^TXX^Tx)=x^T\mathbb E(XX^T)x$. This is equal to $\|x\|^2$ for all $x$ if and only if $\mathbb E(XX^T)$ is the identity.